# c#, Get index of current T in List<T>

Tags: c#, arraylist

I searched quite a bit, i might have Stumbled upon something simmilar but it's stil unlear to me as im new to  c#.

**i want to get current index of the object *Tline*  from a *List< Tline >***
i know i can simply iterate with an int i. but i dont understand why or how i can get it as **indexof  current iteam i'm possitioned on  without searching for anything.**

Tline is something like

```
public class Tline
    {
        public string Cd_m { get; set; }           
        public string cd_d { get; set; }
        public string cd_c { get; set; }
       ...
    }
```

---

My  Issue is here(indicated with arrows)

```
  class ACCS 
{
    internal void DBwrite(List<Tline> imoprtati)
    {
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

        string sFld = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string dbName = "EDIM1.mdb";
        dbName = Path.Combine(sFld, dbName);
        string accessConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", dbName);

        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO DOTes (`id`,`cd_m`,`cd_d`,`cd_c`,`nume`) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

        myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(accessConn);
        int i = 2;
         foreach (var insT in imoprtati)
         {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, myAccessConn))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd_m", "2018");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd_d", "BO");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd_c", "C00128");

                //  Show current Tline  Index                           ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", (imoprtati.GetEnumerator().Current)); //trying anything
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


                cmd.Connection.Close();
                i++;

            }
         }
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `imoprtati.IndexOf(Current)`?

Comment: It's probably better to use a `for` loop in this since you need both the index and the associated item

Comment: @vc74 actually probably not (at least, if you're a pedant) - due to how `List<T>`'s custom struct iterator works vs the indexers, it could work out quite a bit more expensive to use `for`; if this was an array: you'd be absolutely right

Comment: The `List` does not guarante the order. If you want to avoid weird things you should consider changing it to `SortedList`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for mentioning this, a case where a `for` loop might be slower than `foreach`. I guess this will create even more confusion for the OPs believing "Never use foreach, it's slower than for". But I would only take this argument in consideration if the number of items to process is huge and choose readability over micro optimization if it's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List.GetEnumerator().Current will create a new enumerator for the list and then return the current *item*, not index. This will not work as you have seen.

As List implements IList, you can use the IndexOf(T item); method to find the 0 based index of an item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_IList_1_IndexOf__0_

However, this method does not guarantee constant O(1) performance as it must search through the list. A better alternative would be to record the index as you iterate through them as you have stated.

There is no way to find the index of an arbitrary item in a list in constant time without recording the index, so that is what I would recommend.

Comment: Iterating over all the items and searching for each item's index is guaranteed to produce **n * (n + 1)** scans which is definitely not the best solution compared to the other suggestions on this page.

Comment: I suggested the same solution as the other answer while providing an alternative, noting the drawbacks. OP directly asked how to get the index of an arbitrary list item. This is how you do that.

Comment: I'm just stressing on the fact your alternative is indeed better :)

Comment: @WayneGore "OP directly asked how to get the index of an arbitrary list item" - no, they asked how to get the index of the *current* item being iterated - not quite the same thing; they also say, in bold "without searching for anything"

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes it does seem that I misspoke about his intention there. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

`imoprtati.GetEnumerator().Current` won't work, because you are creating a **separate** iterator with it's own position (before the first item currently). Your best bet here is probably a simple counter:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var insT in imoprtati) {
    // your stuff here...


    index++;
}
```

There *is* a LINQ method that includes the index, but that will end up being less efficient due to custom struct iterators, captured variables, etc (complex topic).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! I've deleted my previous comment.